# Why mysql does sleep on valid query and takes twice as long on an invalid request

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I was digging something on a SQL trouble and I saw that a sleep(2) took 4s for example after I saw that it was an old CentOS 6 with an old MySQL

but I was able to reproduce this simple case locally and I have the same behavior on an Ubuntu 20.04 with mariadb :

```
MariaDB [tmp]> select * from users;
+----+----------+
| id | username |
+----+----------+
|  1 | admin    |
|  2 | jdoe     |
+----+----------+
2 rows in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [tmp]> select * from users where username = 'admin';
+----+----------+
| id | username |
+----+----------+
|  1 | admin    |
+----+----------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [tmp]> select * from users where username = 'admin' or sleep(2);
+----+----------+
| id | username |
+----+----------+
|  1 | admin    |
+----+----------+
1 row in set (2.006 sec)

MariaDB [tmp]> select * from users where username = 'admin' or sleep(2) limit 1;
+----+----------+
| id | username |
+----+----------+
|  1 | admin    |
+----+----------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [tmp]> select * from users where username = 'nonexistant' or sleep(2) limit 1;
Empty set (4.006 sec)

MariaDB [BofT]> delete from users where username = 'jdoe';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.002 sec)

MariaDB [tmp]> select * from users where username = 'admin' or sleep(2);
+----+----------+
| id | username |
+----+----------+
|  1 | admin    |
+----+----------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [tmp]> select * from users where username = 'nonexistant' or sleep(2) limit 1;
Empty set (2.001 sec)
```

I created the base with only this :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  username VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO users (id, username) VALUES (1, 'admin');
INSERT INTO users (id, username) VALUES (2, 'jdoe');
```

For example why the third request `select * from users where username = 'admin' or sleep(2);` that is valid still takes two seconds?

Comment: rdms have complex parser to check for a valid query, as it doesn't fond the common validation it cheks the depth of the program which takes time

Comment: It is not clear what different behaviour you expect. Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description which query with what example data and `sleep()` statement you want to call, what execution time you expect and **why** you expect that specific execution time. From the queries shown everything looks as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the WHERE condition can be optimized using indexes, the database will scan the table sequentially, evaluating the condition for each row. Based on your results, the `username` column is not indexed, so we can ignore that optimization.

The `OR` operator performs [short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), so `username = "something" OR sleep(2)` will only sleep if the username is not equal to `something`. If you instead wrote `WHERE sleep(2) OR username = "something"` it will sleep for every row that it tests.

Additionally, if you have a `LIMIT` clause, it will stop scanning once it has found that many matching rows.

When you put all this together, it means that the query will sleep 2 seconds for every row in the table that it scans before it finds one with the matching username. If there are no matching usernames, it will sleep 2 seconds for every row in the table.